# Web Analytics Web Part displaying "There are no results to display" message

Tags: web-part, web-analytics

I am a regular sharepoint user, not an administrator. I've create a Site under My Content and populated it with a dozen pages over the last 10 days or so. On the site home page I've added two *Web Analytics Web Parts*.

The first is set for: *Most Viewed Content*, *This Site and Subsites*, and *preceding 180 days* (though it doesn't matter how many days are selected). It always says:

```
Most viewed pages
(under http://mysites/users/username/a-site)

There are no results to display.
```

The 2nd is set for: *Most Frequent Site Search Queries*, *preceding 180 days*, and shows results.

The *Site Web Analytics Reports - Summary* page has data:

```
Data Last Updated: 6/28/2012 2:00:07 AM
Category    Metrics                         Current Previous    Trend
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Traffic             
    Total Number of Page Views                  811     0           -
    Average Number of Page Views per Day         27     0           -
    Total Number of Daily Unique Visitors        18     0           -
    Average Number of Unique Visitors per Day     1     0           -
    Total Number of Referrers                    14     0           -
    Average Number of Referrers per Day           0     0           -
Inventory               
    Total Number of Sites                         1     0
```

So what could be causing *Most Viewed Content* to be empty and how might I fix it?

**update:** oh that's interesting, I have the same symptoms as this closed question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/ Clicking on links in the results returned from "Most Frequent Site Search Queries" returns "we did not find any results".

Answer (score 1):

I heard back from IT, the MySites search engine and it has not been configured to index personal sites (yet). This explains the empty search results, but not the empty Most Viewed Pages, because the stats are there, but I bet the answer is the same: that option has not been turned on for personal sites.